# Getting "no module named builtin" ImportError

Tags: python, syntax-error, importerror, built-in, psychopy

I'm getting:

```
"ImportError: No module named builtins"
```

that has only started happening after I installed a later version of `PsychoPy` (an application that uses Python that is used for writing psychology experiments). I was not getting this problem with an older version

I tried doing `"sudo pip install future"` like someone else recommended for fixing a similar problem. However, when I do this I get an `"invalid syntax" error`, and don't know of any other way around the problem. I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you trying to import builtins from `future`?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?  I ask because on python 2 it is called `__builtins__` but python 3 uses `builtins`.

Comment: Python 2.7.11. I literally had the exact same code before upgrading PsychoPy without having this problem. I'm pretty sure I haven't upgraded Python.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

Could it be you enter the command into a Python prompt? You are supposed to enter that command on the command line of your operating system shell. Which means not inside Python.

**Original Answer**

Like Deesha already mentioned in their comment, you must install the `future` package into the Python environment you wish to run PsychoPy in, e.g. via pip:

`pip install future`

or via conda:

`conda install future`

This is because newer versions of PsychoPy support both Python 2.7 and 3. The `future` package is used to ensure the code runs on both platforms.

Comment: Yes, like I said in my post, I keep getting an invalid syntax error when I try and do this in the command prompt.

Comment: I think you're not entering this command at the right place. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I realized before that I don't have pip installed. I am trying to do it now but I can't understand how to do it. I'm really bad at doing these things.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Windows? How did you install Python?

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn’t be easier for you to simply install the PsychoPy standalone package.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. I can't remember how I installed Python, as it was a long time ago that I did this.

Comment: In that case I would strongly urge you to use the PsychoPy standalone package, which you can download from https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/releases/tag/1.90.3 Otherwise you will keep running into issues.

Comment: I can't actually remember if I'm already using the standalone package at the moment. Everytime I try and run PsychoPy to try and see what version I have installed it does not launch and I don't know why (I looked up this information and couldn't find an answer on it). I don't even see the sign appear on the taskbar.

Comment: Simply get a new PsychoPy standalone installer and run it then :)

Comment: OK. Would I have to uninstall the current verstion of PsychoPy (in the "Add or remove programs" section of the control panel) first before doing this?

Comment: Normally not, but you can do it just to be sure.

Comment: OK. I did that and downloaded the standalone .dmg file. However, when I double-click on the downloaded file, I'm told that "Windows can't open this file" and that I have to select from a list of installed programs or use the web service to find the correct program."

Comment: You are using Windows. You need to download the .exe installer. .dmg files are for Macs only.